# Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'TextEditingController'

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error when I tried to send data to an API endpoint in Flutter.
I don't seem to understand where the error is coming from.

Here is my data:

```
     var data = {
      'first_name': widget.first_name.toString(),
      'last_name': widget.last_name.toString(),
      'username': username.text,
      'email': widget.email.toString(),
      'mobile_number': widget.mobile_number.toString(),
      'password': password.text,
      'gender': gender,
      'repeat_password': repeat_password.text,
      'dob': dob,
      'accepted_terms': 'on'
    };
```

Comment: Please show more code about your issue, is not enough to just put a variable in it...

Answer (score 1):

Here ,
If value contains `objects` that are not directly `encodable` to a `JSON` string (a value that is not a `number`, `boolean`, `string`, `null`, `list` or a `map` with string `keys`), the `toEncodable` function is used to convert it to an object that must be directly `encodable`.

```
const data = {};
final String jsonString = jsonEncode(data);
print(jsonString);
```